# Spring Security: transferring passwords

Tags: https, passwords, spring-security

Im developing a web application with java and Spring Security 3.0.5 and I am pretty new to it. I have a community where users can register and log in. Now I wonder how informations (like password) can be securely transferred to the server so that other people cant read it out. I guess it would work of course with HTTPS, but are there any other solutions/possibilities? (Maybe some offered by Spring Security?)

Comment: Are you referring to data migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say SSL/HTTPS is the best choice.

You just need to enable it on your server. You can map your SSL port in your namespace config like [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?109361-How-does-Spring-Security-determine-SSL-port).

[This](http://www.berwickheights.com/wordpress/2009/11/spring-security-ssl-and-tomcat/) might help you if you're using Tomcat.